# react vertical carousel with react-image-gallery

Tags: reactjs, carousel

I am using [react-image-gallery](https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery)

how to auto-play images vertically?

the problem is to view them vertically like below

[image: vertical slider]

```
import ImageGallery from 'react-image-gallery';
function HomePage(props) {
   const imagesFromFolder = [
    {
        original: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1000/600/',
        thumbnail: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1015/250/150/',
    }];

 return (

    <div className="home-page"> <div className="sidenav" style={{ width: "450px" }}>
            <ImageGallery disableThumbnailScroll={false} showThumbnails={true} showNav={false}
                isRTL={false} autoPlay={true} thumbnailPosition="left"
                stopPropagation={true}
                items={imagesFromFolder} />
/>
 </div >
);
 }
export default HomePage;
```

update 
Is there is a way to do that?

Comment: Please add more details and code to show your effort at trying to solve the problem, it would be much easier to answer your question that way.

Comment: In `react-image-gallery` there is a prop `autoPlay`, you can use it. https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery read the docs for more information.

Comment: @Roy i added some code

Comment: @BHAR4T my problem is to view them vertically below each other like attached image

Comment: any solution? @mohamedhamada

Comment: @sultanaslam sorry no

Answer (score 0):

Let's add property:
thumbnailPosition='left'